# init let variable based on a boolean

Tags: swift, immutability, variable-initialization

I use Swift 3 and I want to init a String let variable based on a boolean. I know how to do it with a standard if statement with a var variable but not as a one line expression.

With Java i would do:

```
String str = myBool ? "John" : "Peter";
```

Is there a equivalent​ with Swift 3 to not use a var and in a one-line way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift, like Java, supports this [ternary operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71).

```
var str = myBool ? "John" : "Peter"
```

Comment: That was I was thinking of but with a let variable. Actually it doesn't really l'atterrissage if it is a var or let, I wish a one-line expression as you suggest.

Comment: Sorry for bad comment! (Damned app!). XCode was saying that "Consecutive statements must be seperated by ";". After clean and build, it looks OK now. Thank you.

Comment: I would add that spaces are really important with this code, as ? As à meaning at the end of variable name

Comment: Nitpick: This is called the *conditional operator* (apple calls it the *ternary conditional operator*). It happens to be the only ternary operator that exists. But calling it the ternary operator is like referring to `+` as the `binary operator`.

Comment: @Alexander that's why I used "this" instead of "the".